# Can't figure out how to keep a saved answer when continuing a loop

Tags: java

hello everybody i'm working on an assignment and I can't figure out how to save my highest value in my loop for my program which is supposed to read all the characters in a sentence and tell me what the longest reoccuring character is for example if i input hellllo the answer should be 4 and i have that done, however if i have other character strings 2 or higher before or after it won't just have the highest number for example - hhhiiiills should be 4 but it is 7. here is my code I am a java noob and we use the HSA console format in class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class Assignment6
{
    static Console c;
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Console c = new Console ("Largest Group");
        c.println ("Enter a sentence");
        String sentence = c.readLine ();
        int sentenceGrp = sizeOfLargestGroup (sentence);
        c.print (sentenceGrp);
    }

    private static int sizeOfLargestGroup (String grp)
    {
        int numGrp = 1;
        int grouplength = grp.length ();
        int largestcount = 1;
        char grpNew = grp.charAt (0);
        for (int position = 1 ; position < grouplength ; position++)
        {
            char grpNew1 = grp.charAt (position);
            if (grpNew == grpNew1)
            {
                numGrp++;
            }
            else
            {
                grpNew = grp.charAt (position);
            }
        }
        return numGrp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it have to recur consecutively?  For example, should Mississippi return 2 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

You should reset NumGrp variable to 1 when symbol is changed and keep the largest group length in grouplength variable.

```
private static int sizeOfLargestGroup (String grp)
{
    // check that string is not empty
    if (grp == null || grp.length() == 0) return 0;

    int numGrp = 1;
    int grouplength = grp.length();
    int largestcount = 1;
    char grpNew = grp.charAt (0);
    for (int position = 1 ; position < grouplength ; position++)
    {
        char grpNew1 = grp.charAt (position);
        if (grpNew == grpNew1)
        {
            numGrp++;

        }

        else
        {
            if (numGrp > largestcount) largestcount = numGrp ;
            // reset NumGrp and remember the last symbol
            numGrp = 1;
            grpNew = grp.charAt (position);
        }

    }
    // check the last sequence
    if (numGrp > largestcount) largestcount = numGrp ;
    return largestcount ;
}
```